# Would it be considered rude to describe my Australian passport as having 优势 ("superiority"), and is there a better phrasing?

Tags: word-choice, equivalent-phrase

> [CC-CEDICT](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E4%BC%98%E5%8A%BF): 优势 (yōu​shì​) superiority / dominance / advantage

I recall at one point having a conversation with a Chinese person about international travel, and regarding my passport, I said something like:

> 我的护照很有优势。

This could translate to either:

> My (Australian) passport is superior.
> My (Australian) passport has advantages.

Objectively, I mean that I can go to many countries [without a visa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_requirements_for_Australian_citizens), unlike people [on a Chinese passport](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_requirements_for_Chinese_citizens).  But in hindsight, the way I expressed it sounds rude, arrogant, and elitist.

**Question**: Would it be considered rude to describe my Australian passport as having 优势 ("superiority"), and is there a better phrasing?

Maybe there's a more tactful (委婉) way of expressing this concept.

Comment: Maybe 很有 vs. 比较有, i.e.: is comparatively advantageous. | 免签 is also a word you might want to know.

Comment: Personally, I would drop 我的護照 if it's clear from context that you're an Australian citizen and say 澳洲護照 instead. I would also drop broad sweeping-statements like 優勢 if you're talking about going to specific countries, and say 澳洲護照去某某國家不用簽證.

Answer (score 4):

To be more 委婉, I may use 方便 (convenient) instead of 优势.

Answer (score 1):

This phrasing is not rude, but if you want to be more tactful, you may say it even more objectively:

> 我的護照可以免簽證去很多國家。(literally "I can go to many countries without a visa with my passport.")

Answer (score 1):

> 我的护照很有优势。

You shall supplement this sentence with a clause to avoid the sense of "superiority".

- 出國旅遊, 我的护照很**佔/具优势**。- The passport I held is much more **advantageous** in foreign travel.
- 出國旅遊, 我的护照很**方便/好使/好用** - The passport I held is more **convenient** for foreign travel.

It would be more clear if "我" is replaced with the name of a specific country, such as "美國/新加坡/..的护照".

Answer (score 0):

> go to many countries without a visa

the proper term is [visitor] visa waiver, or visa exemption.

so, maybe you can say:

my [aussie] passport is more visa-waived

my [aussie] passport is more visa-exempted

have fun :)